# Can I calculate the t-value only using mean and standard deviation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Can I calculate the t-value of some population, if I only know the mean and standard deviation of the data and not the actual data itself. If not, what are the values I should know to calculate the t-value of the data?

Comment: Do you know the sample size?  If not then assume a large number and use the normal distribution.

Comment: @Dave2e The sample size does affect the degrees of freedom, yes, but it also comes up in the calculation of the test statistic itself (whether you use the t-stat or z-stat).

Comment: Yes, I do know the sample size. Do you mean to generate a normal distribution in some software (eg. numpy.random.normal)?

Comment: Getting the entire distribution is a separate issue. The gist is that, if you draw your $n$ observations from a normal distribution, the $t$ given in my answer will have a $t_{n-1}$ distribution. However, that is a theoretical distribution, not one you need to simulate for a typical t-test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you also need the sample size, $n$.

$$
t=\dfrac{
\bar x -\mu_0
}{
s/\sqrt n
}
$$

(It is typical, but not necessary, to assume $\mu_0=0$.)